# Convert different date format string into datetime format

Tags: python

I have a column of date with different format of date

```
publish_date = ["Feb. 2, 2000", "June 4, 1989", "Mar. 13, 2018"]
```

I was using `strptime()` to convert one type of string, how can I convert multiple formats of date in the same column?

```
type 1: %b %d, %Y

type 2: %B %d, %Y
```

Comment: Not that easy... I guess You'd have to make some kind of `if` structure to find out which format is applied and then use `strptime` accordingly.

Comment: You could use this 3rd party module http://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the 3rd party [dateparser module](http://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest)

Install with `pip install dateparser`, then

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> publish_date = ["Feb. 2, 2000", "June 4, 1989", "Mar. 13, 2018"]
>>> for d in publish_date:
...     print(dateparser.parse(d))
... 
2000-02-02 00:00:00
1989-06-04 00:00:00
2018-03-13 00:00:00
```

`dateparser` accepts a huge range of formats, but you can restrict it to just the ones you're interested in if you like

```
>>> for d in publish_date:
...     print(dateparser.parse(d, date_formats=['%b %d, %Y', '%B %d, %Y']))
... 
2000-02-02 00:00:00
1989-06-04 00:00:00
2018-03-13 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **[dateutil](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)**

**Demo:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse 
publish_date = ["Feb. 2, 2000", "June 4, 1989", "Mar. 13, 2018"]
for date in publish_date:
    print( parse(date) )
```

**Output:**

```
2000-02-02 00:00:00
1989-06-04 00:00:00
2018-03-13 00:00:00
```